# Displaying the unique elements from the two columns in two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data1 = {'date': ['1998', '1999','1999','2000','1999'], 
        'node1': [1,1,2,3,3],
     'node2': [3,4,3,4,8],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1,1], }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['date', 'node1','node2','weight'])

data2 = {'date': ['2002','2001','2003','2002','2002','2001'], 
        'node1': [1,1,1,2,2,3],
     'node2': [2,3,4,3,5,4],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1,1,1], }
df2= pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['date', 'node1','node2','weight'])
```

I would like to search through the two columns (node1,node2) in the two dataframes and display the node which are unique in the two dataframes.
In this example 8 from data1 and 5 from data2 are the unique nodes in the dataframe.

Output Format:

dataframe1:  8 1999

dataframe2:  5 2002

Comment: Is it okay to display the output in one dataframe?

Comment: I would like to display them as separate dataframes.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. You just want to check if a single node is unique. Not the combination! Hmm, jez's answer might be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) for get unique values, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
a = df1.drop('weight',1).melt('date', value_name='node').drop('variable',1)
b = df2.drop('weight',1).melt('date', value_name='node').drop('variable',1)
```

Faster alternative:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'date':np.repeat(df1['date'], 2), 
                  'node':df1[['node1','node2']].values.ravel()})
b = pd.DataFrame({'date':np.repeat(df2['date'], 2), 
                  'node':df2[['node1','node2']].values.ravel()})
```

---

```
c = pd.merge(a, b, how='outer', indicator=True, on='node')

d = c.loc[c['_merge'] == 'left_only', ['date_x', 'node']]
print (d)
   date_x  node
25   1999     8

e = c.loc[c['_merge'] == 'right_only', ['date_y', 'node']]
print (e)
   date_y  node
26   2002     5
```

Detail:

```
print (a)
   date  node
0  1998     1
1  1999     1
2  1999     2
3  2000     3
4  1999     3
5  1998     3
6  1999     4
7  1999     3
8  2000     4
9  1999     8

print (b)
    date  node
0   2002     1
1   2001     1
2   2003     1
3   2002     2
4   2002     2
5   2001     3
6   2002     2
7   2001     3
8   2003     4
9   2002     3
10  2002     5
11  2001     4
```

Comment: My actual date is in the format 1998-03-12.Will that make a difference?Thanks

Comment: The error coming is keyerror:'date' for the first line

Comment: It is your column name `date`, what is `print (df1.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: The faster alternative is really really helpful in the case of medium to large datasets.Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157635/discussion-between-chaitali-sarkar-and-jezrael).