# Searching unique elements in the two columns of the two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From here [Displaying the unique elements from the two columns in two dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967505/displaying-the-unique-elements-from-the-two-columns-in-two-dataframe)

```
data1 = {'date': ['1998', '1999','1999','2000','1999'], 
        'node1': [1,1,2,3,3],
     'node2': [3,4,3,4,8],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1,1], }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['date', 'node1','node2','weight'])

data2 = {'date': ['2002','2001','2003','2002','2002','2001'], 
        'node1': [1,1,1,2,2,3],
     'node2': [2,3,4,3,5,4],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1,1,1], }
df2= pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['date', 'node1','node2','weight'])
```

I would like to search through the two columns (node1,node2) in the two dataframes and display the node which are unique in the two dataframes. In this example 8 from data1 and 5 from data2 are the unique nodes in the dataframe.

Output Format:

dataframe1: 8

dataframe2: 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bit modified previous answer with `merge`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'node':df1[['node1','node2']].values.ravel()})
b = pd.DataFrame({'node':df2[['node1','node2']].values.ravel()})

c = pd.merge(a, b, how='outer', indicator=True, on='node')
#
d = c.loc[c['_merge'] == 'left_only', ['node']]
print (d)
    node
25     8

e = c.loc[c['_merge'] == 'right_only', ['node']]
print (e)
    node
26     5
```

But if performance is important, use [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
a = df1[['node1','node2']].values.ravel()
b = df2[['node1','node2']].values.ravel()

d = np.setdiff1d(a,b)
print (d)
[8]

e = np.setdiff1d(b,a)
print (e)
[5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.concat` and `pd.Series.drop_duplicates`

```
cols = ['node1', 'node2']
pd.concat(
    [d[cols] for d in [df1, df2]],
    keys=[1, 2]
).stack().drop_duplicates(keep=False).reset_index([1, 2], drop=True)

1    8
2    5
dtype: int64
```